# login to postgres as another user gives FATAL error

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres server and I don't want django to login as postgres user, so I created a user called django with `createuser --interactive -P django`.

I want to login as django over ssh but when I try `psql -U django -W` it gives me this error:

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "django"
```

Comment: A key missing point in your question is how to want to secure local connections. 1: with a password. 2: by requiring the same OS username than DB username ("peer" authentication, your current setup according to the error msg). 3: by allowing any OS user without any password ("trust") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to authorize your new user to connect to database by editing your `pg_hba.conf` file (often located on `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf` with `9.4` being your installed version of PostgreSQL).

Do to so, add a line on it like this one :

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   django          django                                  trust
```

Supposing that you created a database name `django` for your `django` user.
It only allow your user to connect locally, if you want to allows him to connect via TCP/IP, line is more like

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    django          django          192.168.12.10/32        md5
```

Where `192.168.12.10` is the IP from where your `django` user will reach your database.

Read comments on `pg_hba.conf` file, they explain pretty well how it works. Or have a look at [this documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) on PostgreSQL website.

Comment: Is this the easiest way to configure django to connect to postgres?

Comment: It is not about django, it's the way PostgreSQL works. But one it's configured, you don't have to touch it anymore.